rembg_cars: {"error": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'carros.pth'"}
I am trying to remove BG from car using rembg-cars Python package. But here I am facing a problem.
{"error": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'carros.pth'"}..
Most likely here have not given the custom model. How effective (rembg-cars) Python package?
output_data = remove(input_data , model_name="carros")

The github link for it is dead https://github.com/poropeza/rembg_cars and https://pypi.org/project/rembg-cars/#history doesn't look promising. The library code does path = os.environ.get("U2NET_PATH", os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~", ".u2net", model_name + ".pth")),) ...it looks like this lib only ever worked for the author and is unusable by anyone else.

How can i get or solve this issue? @Anentropic
